# Routing of flutter web app hosted on Google Cloud Storage is not working

Tags: flutter, routes, gcloud

I am hosting a Flutter web app on Google Cloud Storage which works fine and is accessible via my sub domain `app.mydomain.com`. In general i'm pretty happy with Google Cloud Storage since it is easy to deploy and the costs of hosting are cheap.

Unfortunately, routing is a problem.
When i navigate via the app to the login page the address bar changes to  `app.mydomain.com/login` and the login page is shown. But when i reload the page via the browser's reload button, I see the following XML

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

I assume this is because Google Cloud Storage wants to fetch the index.html file in the `login` folder. However, the bucket does not contain such a `login` folder.

## Question:

- How can I get this running?
- Is it possible to deactivate the feature of fetching subfolders within a bucket to redirect the information of the address bar to my flutter app?
- What would be a cheap alternative if there is no alternative?

Comment: Hi, When you reload the page, what url do you see? Can you share the code snippet of the redirection? Do you also have a script when you refresh a page? Kindly provide that as well but please omit sensitive information. Also did you follow [Cloud Storage Hosting a static website tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)?

Comment: When i reload on `app.mydomain.com/login` i also see `app.mydomain.com/login` as the URL. However with the XML error shown in my post. I read and followed the tutorial linked by you.

Comment: Have you configured main_page_prefix as mentioned in the [web description](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#description)? Can you provide details regarding that?

Comment: i haven't. i'll check it out and report back! Thanks!

Comment: This was actually my fault and a flutter related problem. But thanks for your help i highly appreciate it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem.

If you pay close attention the the URL which i've posted in the question you might notice that the URL lacks the `#` character which is normally present. This is because i've had set `setPathUrlStrategy()` from the [`url_strategy`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy) package.

So instead of using `app.mydomain.com/login` my URL now looks like this `app.mydomain.com/#/login` which causes Google Cloud storage to correctly forward the URL to my application instead of trying to fetch a file or folder within the bucket.